# Want a new tag, e.g. for office work and academic work?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think we could use a new tag, for people who ask on this site about (I'm not sure) the connection between their work and Buddhism -- especially, office-work or mental work.

Examples of questions include:

- [Software programming/Art and Buddhist Practice - Pursuing creative activity](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/13416/254)
- [Scientific Problem solving and Wu Wei](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/19767/254)
- [Is Buddhism against scientific attitude?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/19695/254)
- [Can meditation help students in exams?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/5679/254)
- [How to be mindful while studying?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/9001/254)
- [Can meditation help me in my academics?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/8745/254)
- [How to reconcile non-attachment in a Type-A, North American culture where work is life?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/26341/254)

A characteristic of these questions is that they're about lay pursuits.

A benefit of a tag would be that people who ask a question like this could also find previous answers to related topics.

- What would be a good title for new tag? Something to do with "mind", "mindfulness", or "meditation" perhaps (or, not, because these are lay and not traditionally Buddhist activities)? Something like "science" or "modern-world" (or, not, because "science" is too restrictive and excludes students, and "modern-world" is too inclusive of too many other topics)?
- As a bonus can you also suggest the "wiki text" (the description) associated with the new tag: which explains what topic[s] this new tag is or isn't used for?

---

In general I recommend we don't define a new tag that's only used for one question: a tag is useful to identify a group of related questions; especially when those questions don't necessarily all contain the same word (e.g. "science" or whatever), which a user can find using Search instead of using a tag.

Comment: Maybe `worldly` or `worldly-affairs` or `worldly-pursuits`

Comment: I asked [this question on English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/386400/9548), I think the best reply there was `knowledge-worker`.

Comment: `knowledge-worker` may seem a bit odd for this purpose? Say a person is going to ask a question about studies. It is unlikely they might search for this tag. Just my thinking.

Comment: I doubt they'll search for `wordly` either. I expect I will be someone who might add a tag to existing questions if I notice them ... the point of the tag is so people (including me) can find similar topics after they're tagged.

Comment: Or `student` might have been good (people might look for that tag) ... except that, on this site, "student" would imply "someone who's studying Buddhism": which isn't what I want this tag for. I want this tag for people/topics that ask how Buddhist practice might help or might hinder their lay knowledge-work or lay studying.

Comment: Yes. How about `householder`? `For question related to householder's affairs and pursuits which include work, studying, family matters, medical issues, etc.`.

Comment: `householder` (or `lay`) would include for example [Is it okay to seek financial gains as a layman?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/15700/254) plus a huge variety of other topics (sexuality and ethics etc). I want a narrow tag for questions like "Will practicing meditation help my studies?" and "How can I be 'mindful' when I'm programming?"

Comment: `meditation-daily-activities`

Comment: `buddhist-techniques-as-tools` comes to mind...

Comment: `daily-job` perhaps?

Comment: I like `meditation-daily-activities`, except that it's unusual to have a 3-word tag, and I'm not sure it's necessarily meditation (though it's neat to fit it into the spectrum of existing meditation-xxx tags) `daily-activities` or `daily-job` may be enough.